# UAE Long Term Visa Validity

Tags: visas, uae

I applied for a 90-day visa and got a long-term visit, single-entry tourist visa. The date given is 12-May-2016, and it's valid until 12-July-2016.

My agent says the 12-July is the latest date I can travel to Dubai; once I enter I need to count 90 days. If I enter on 23th May, shall I count 90 days from that day?

Is it true, or where can I get it checked?

Answer (score 1):

According to the UAE Embassy web-site, your visa has a validity period of 60 days, starting from the day it was issued (12 May). This means you can use the visa to fly to and enter the country any time from 12 May until 12 July.

If it is a 90-day visa, and you say it is, then you can stay in the UAE for up to 90 days from the date of entry. If you enter the UAE on 12 June, you get 90 days from that day, if you wait until 10 July, you get 90 days from then. You'll get two stamps upon arrival, one an entry stamp with the date of entry, and one that says "VALID 90 DAYS STAY FROM DATE OF ARRIVAL". It will be on you to determine what the 90 days is, so ASK the officer...

Lastly, since you've got a single entry visa, once you actually use it to enter the country, of course, it is no longer valid for you to use again.